# Does flash.display.Loader determine the file by filename or header?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Does flash.display.Loader determine the file by filename or header?

The reason why I ask is that I'm getting an IOError: "Unknown File Type" when loading an swf which has a strange filename (in the form of "filename.randomnumbersandletters.swf").

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the file `filename.randomnumbersandletters.swf` itself is valid SWF?

Comment: And have you tried renaming the file to see if it loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to [encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) (escape(file_path)) the swf file url as it might contain some special character. And flash loader determines the file type by header instead of filename.